# Function $g(x)$ that is an Integer if and only if $x$ and $f(x)$ are Integers

Tags: functions, roots, integers

Let $g(x)$ be a continuous function that is an integer if and only if $x$ and $f(x)$ ($f(x)$ can be any function) are both integers. What is one definition of $g(x)$ that does not include trigonometric functions ($\sin$, $\cos$, $\tan$, or any of the many variants), $\max$ or $\min$? $g(x)$ should also be efficiently computable given that $f(x)$ is efficiently computable as well.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net as an example, use $33/x$ or $\sqrt{x}$ (sorry, just made these up on the spot).

Comment: Unfortunately, you would need something that's periodic, or contains a periodic componenrt

Comment: @SakethMalyala Let me edit the question then.

Comment: @ShreyJoshi Well, modulo is not usually continuous so I don't know how that helps.

Comment: What's $f$ got to do with $g$ or anything.  Let $g(x) =x$ and $f(x) = x$.

Comment: Whether a definition of $g(x)$ "includes" certain other functions depends entirely on how you choose to write the definition and so that constraint is basically meaningless.  I would suggest you instead clarify what kinds of constructions you _do_ want to allow when defining $g(x)$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Well, I'm open to basically any idea, so trying to clamp down will inevitably throw out a possibility I haven't even considered.

Comment: @fleablood Well, $f(x)$ can be any function.

Comment: So do piecewise functions.  Let $A=\{x\in \mathbb Z| f(x)\in\mathbb Z\}$.  Put $A$ in order so that $A = \{a_i\}$ where $a_i < a_{i+1}$ (you can use negative indexes is $A$ isn't bounded below).  If $a_i \le x \le a_{i+1}$ let $h(x) = i + (x-a_i)\frac 1{a_{i+1}-a_{i}}$.  That's a piecewise but continuous function that will equal $i$ when $x=a_i$ and so $f(x)$ is an integer but will be a value between $i$ and $i+1$ for all values between $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$ where neither $x$ for $f(x)$ is an integer.  If $A$ is bounded above or below you can make altercations.

Comment: @fleablood Thank you for reminding me of a condition. See edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure if it’s possible for any function $f(x)$, but if $f(x)$ is continuous:

Let $h(x) = \frac{( x - \lfloor x \rfloor ) + ( \lceil x \rceil - x ) }{2} - \frac{\left| ( x - \lfloor x \rfloor ) - ( \lceil x \rceil - x ) \right|}{2}$. If you graph this, you’ll see that it’s continuous, and equals zero if and only if $x$ is an integer. Also note that $\frac{1}{2} \geq h(x) \geq 0$.

Then if $f(x)$ is continuous, $h(f(x))$ is continuous and equal to zero if and only if $f(x)$ is an integer.

Then let $g(x) = \frac{ h(x) + h(f(x))}{2} + \frac{\left| h(x) - h(f(x)) \right|}{2}$, which is continuous, and is zero if and only if both $h(x)$ and $h(f(x))$ are zero (since $h$ is non-negative), and is always less than one, hence is an integer if and only if both $x$ and $f(x)$ are integers.

Comment: I did say without using $\min$ or $\max$, though.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were saying without trig, and was proposing max or min instead. I’ll edit my answer.

Comment: Please look at my (slightly) edited question.

Comment: Thank you. I'll wait for others until I accept.

Comment: Your question went from $g(x) = 0$ if and only if $x$ and $f(x)$ are both integers, to $g(x)$ is INTEGER only when $x$ and $f(x)$ are both integers, and you consider that a SLIGHT change?

Comment: Well, yeah (especially when you consider $0$ IS technically an integer, though not at all what the spirit of the question means, which I think you know by now).

Comment: Actually, I’m just lucky that the function I constructed was always less than one, otherwise it could have easily been an integer when neither $x$ nor $f(x)$ was an integer.  By the way way, with your new edit of “Integer only when”, do you mean “if and only if”?  My answer is “if and only if”, but if you leave the question worded as is, others may answer with functions that only satisfy “only when”.

Comment: Well, I did say "if and only if" in the body, but not the title, so duly noted and corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be all integers $a$ where $f(a)$ is an integer.

You want $h(x)$ to be an integer if and only if $x \in A$.

Either $A$ is empty, $A$ is non-empty and finite, $A$ is infinite but has a least element (but not a greatest), $A$ is infinite but has a greatest element (but not a least), $A$ is infinite but has no least or greatest element.

If $A$ is finite label the elements as $a_0, a_1, a_2, .... ,a_n$ so that $a_i < a_j \iff i < j$.  If $A$ is infinite but has a least element label the elements as $a_0, a_1, a_2, .... $ so that $a_i < a_j \iff i < j$. If $A$ is infinite but has a greatest element label the elements as $.....a_{-2},a_{-1}, a_0$ so that $a_i < a_j \iff i< j$.  If $A$ is infinite and unbounded above or below pick an arbitrary element to be $a_0$ and label the elements as $.....a_{-2},a_{-1}, a_0,a_1,a_2,.....$  so that $a_i < a_j \iff i < j$.

If $A$ is empty then $h(x)$ is never an integer. Let $h(x) = \frac 13$.

If $A$ has a least element $a_0$.  If $x \le a_0$ let $x= \frac 1{a_0 -x + 1} -1$.  Thus $h(a_0) = 0$ and for all $x < a_0$, $-1 < f(x) < 0$ so $h(x)$ will never be an integer for $x < a_0$.  And $h(x)$ will be continuous on $(-\infty, a_0]$

If $A$ has a greatest element $a_n$.  If $x \ge a_n$ let $x = n+ \frac 1{x-a_n +1}-1$.  Thus $h(a_n) = n$ and for all $x> a_n$, $n <f(x) < n+1$ so $h(x)$ will never be an integer for $x > a_n$.  And $h(x)$ will be continuous on $[a_n, \infty)$

For any $x: a_i \le x \le a_{i+1}$ let $h(x) = a_i + (x-a_i)\frac 1{a_{i+1}-a_i}$.  So $h(a_i) =i$ and $h(a_{i+1}) = i+1$ and for all $x: a_i<x < a_{i+1}$ we have  $i < f(x) < i+1$.  And $h(x)$ is continuous on $[a_i, a_{i+1}]$.

This function is continuous and is an integer only when $x$ and $f(x)$ is an integer.

Comment: Well, this isn't very easily computable, especially if you don't know the elements in $A$.

Comment: If $f$ is computable then you do know the elements of $A$, don't you.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you for your answer.